# How can page through the results? laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, frameworks

How can page through the results? .It With ajax.
to bring the data to my view , I want to use paginate () and orderby (), but to put it is in the documentation , it generates error.
if I do so : **$cita= Cita::orderBy(asc)->paginate(10)**, I did not bring the data. Excuse the English 'm Mexican .

**Controller:**

```
    public function agenda(){
    $cita = Cita::all();       
     return  Response()->json(
            $cita->toArray()
        );
}
```

**Script:**

```
function Carga(){
var tablaDatos = $("#datos");
var route = "http://cmec.app/agenda";

$("#datos").empty();
$.get(route, function(res){
    $(res).each(function(key, value){
        tablaDatos.append(
            "<tr><td>"+value.name+"</td><td>"+value.lastname+"</td><td>"+value.doctor+"</td><td>"+value.fecha+"</td><td>"+value.hora+"</td><td><div class='btn-group btn-group-sm' role='group'><button value="+value.id+" OnClick='Mostrar(this);' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></button><button value="+value.id+" OnClick='Mostrar(this); ' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editar-modal' ><i class='fa fa-pencil-square'></i></button></div></td></tr>");
    });
});}
```

**Vista:**

```
            <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Apellidos</th>
                    <th>Doctor</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Hora</th>
                    <th>Acciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="datos"></tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: use `$cita= Cita::orderBy('asc')->paginate(10)` for pagination with order

Comment: "`it generates error`" Please post the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following for you code

**Controller**

```
public function agenda(){
    $cita = Cita::orderBy('asc')->paginate(10);       
    return response()->json($cita->toArray());
}
```

**Script**

```
function Carga(){
    var tablaDatos = $("#datos");
    var route = "http://cmec.app/agenda";

    $("#datos").empty();
    $.getJson(route, function(res){
        $(res).each(function(key, value){
            tablaDatos.append(
                "<tr><td>"+value.name+"</td><td>"+value.lastname+"</td><td>"+value.doctor+"</td><td>"+value.fecha+"</td><td>"+value.hora+"</td><td><div class='btn-group btn-group-sm' role='group'><button value="+value.id+" OnClick='Mostrar(this);' class='btn btn-danger'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></button><button value="+value.id+" OnClick='Mostrar(this); ' class='btn btn-primary' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editar-modal' ><i class='fa fa-pencil-square'></i></button></div></td></tr>");
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error :

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 636:SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'asc' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `Citas` order by `asc` asc limit 10 offset 0)
```